# How to match a word surrounded by punctuation and numbers

Tags: python, regex

I have several words and phrases I'm looking to match. I only want to match them if they are surrounded by spaces or punctuation (including underscores). But I do not want to match them if they are surrounded by letters.

For instance, the regex should match "free money" in

```
[
    'Text me"free money"',
    'Text me" free money please"',
    'free money',
    '12free money',
    '5free money9',
    '_free money_'
]
```

but do not match "free money" in

```
[
    'Text me"germfree money"',
    'germfree money',
    'carefree money',
    'free moneygram'
]
```

I wrote this python to go through my list of `words_to_match`. But I'm having trouble matching when it is surrounded by underscores, or numbers.

```
words_to_match = ['free money']

sentences_to_check = [
        'Text me"free money"',
        'Text me" free money please"',
        'free money',
        '12free money',
        '5free money9',
        '_free money_',
        'Text me"germfree money"',
        'germfree money',
        'carefree money',
        'free moneygram'
    ]

for word in words_to_match:
    word = word.lower()
    for sentence in sentences_to_check:
        sentence = sentence.lower()
        regex = re.compile(fr'[^a-z0-9]?(\b{word}\b)[^a-z0-9]?'.format(word=word))
        z = regex.findall(sentence)
        
        if len(z) > 0:
            print('MATCHED "' + word + '" in ' + sentence)
        else:
            print('No match "' + word + '" in ' + sentence)
```

gives me the result:

> MATCHED "free money" in text me"free money"
> MATCHED "free money" in text me" free money please"
> MATCHED "free money" in free money
> No match "free money" in 12free money  ## I want this to match
> No match "free money" in 5free money9  ## I want this to match
> No match "free money" in *free money*  ## I want this to match
> No match "free money" in text me"germefree money"
> No match "free money" in germfree money
> No match "free money" in carefree money
> No match "free money" in free moneygram

Comment: you say: `[...] match them if they are surrounded by [...], **letters**. But I do not want to match them if they are surrounded by **letters**`

so which is it?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. It's the latter. Fixed.

Comment: There is a little more ambiguity: basically, you're specifying "reject if abutted by letters, accept if abutted by punctuation or spaces or nothing". What qualifies as punctuation? is `∑` punctuation? Is everything that *isn't* a letter ok? Also you have `'5free money9',` in the list of matching strings, but then in the code `0-9` is specified to be excluded.

Comment: To be exact, everything that isn't a letter is ok. I think my code is an attempt but ultimately wrong therefore a bad illustration for the objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `(?<![a-z])free money(?![a-z])` instead.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MJNGBS/2/)

`\b` matches between a character matched by `\w` and a character not matched by `\w` without consuming any character. `\w` translates to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, but you only want `[a-z]` not to be around your word. so you can use `negative look-around` instead.

**Details**

`(?<![a-z])`: `[a-z]` must no match before `f`

`(?![a-z])`: `[a-z]` must no match after `y`

code:

```
regex = re.compile(fr'(?<![a-z]){word}(?![a-z])'.format(word=word))
```

output:

```
MATCHED "free money" in text me"free money"
MATCHED "free money" in text me" free money please"
MATCHED "free money" in free money
MATCHED "free money" in 12free money
MATCHED "free money" in 5free money9
MATCHED "free money" in _free money_
No match "free money" in text me"germfree money"
No match "free money" in germfree money
No match "free money" in carefree money
No match "free money" in free moneygram
```

Comment: In python '\w' is not the same as '[A-Za-z0-9_]'. It matches any unicode letter, which is a *huge* class of characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
r'^(?:.*[^A-Za-z]|)free money(?:[^A-Za-z].*|)$'
```

Explanation:

- Starting at the beginning of the input string...
- ...Create a non-capture group which contains either:

  - Anything (including an empty string), followed by a non-letter, **or**
  - An empty string
- ... Followed by the string "free money" ...
- ... Followed by a non-capture group which container either:

  - A non-letter, followed by anything (including an empty string), **or**
  - An empty string
- ... until the end of the input string.